# Unable To Download code From Appengine - Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

The below is the code I am trying to execute to download the source code from AppEngine:

```
/Users/sridhar/Desktop/backupdata/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4/bin/appcfg.sh download_app -A maharasims2 -V 23 download_app .
```

I am getting the Bad Format error:

```
Bad argument: Expected download directory as an argument after download_app.
AppCfg [options] -A app_id [ -V version ] download_app <out-dir>

Download a previously-uploaded app to the specified directory.  The app
ID is specified by the "-A" option.  The optional version is specified
by the "-V" option.
```

Can anyone help me out?

---

I tried the following and it worked.

**Step 1:** jdk/bin/appcfg.sh -A < apppid > -V < version > download_app < directory >

**Example :**

/Users/Desktop/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4/bin/appcfg.sh -A testapp -V 23 download_app ~/Desktop/backupdata/downloads/

**Step 2:** http://architecturalatrocities.com/post/19073788679/fixing-the-trustanchors-problem-when-running-openjdk-7

**Note :** 
 Use step 2 if you are  encountering the following error :

"java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"

Comment: add the target directory you want the code to go to at the end of the command?

Answer (score 2):

The options should go *before* the command:

```
appcfg.sh -A maharasims2 -V 23 download_app .
```